# Different symbols used in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I use a dot, arrow, or double colon to refer to members of a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c)

Various examples that I see, I've seen them use `::`, `->` and `.` . I usually get confused between the last 2. Can someone help me making it clear about the usage of `->` and `.` in `VC++` about where can I use it and what is the difference!

Comment: The best way to learn C++ is to get [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c

Comment: I'm learning C++ from "Ivor Horton's Visual C++ 2008" book, but I've got the confusion between the symbols "->" and ".", if you could reply to this question with the answer, it would be great.

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->` dereferences the pointer to its left.
`.` uses the object to its left which is not a pointer.

Comment: I got the answer "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c" but anyways thanks for that answer! :D