# Difference between . and :: in C++ for static members?

Tags: c++, static, scope-resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I use a dot, arrow, or double colon to refer to members of a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c)

When I try to access my static variable using `Class.Variable` I get the error that `Error  left of 'Variable' must have class/struct/union` and when I do `Class::Variable` I get no error. Although in both cases I get `Variable` through intellisense. What exactly is the different between `.` and `::` in this case?

Comment: Hmm. Intelisense isn't a compiler.

Comment: You should post the actual code that yields the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static members of a class can be accessed through two ways

(a) With instances of class - Use `.`  e.g. `obj.variable`

(b) Without instance of class - Use `::` e.g. `class::variable`

Comment: or if pointer to object, statics are accessible with ->

Answer (score 2):

`.` is used for objects `::` for class names.

```
 struct foo {
     int x;
     static int y;
 };

 foo bar;

 bar.x = 10; // ok
 bar.y = 20; // ok - but bad practice

 foo.x = 10; // WRONG foo is class name
 foo.y = 20; // WRONG foo is class name

 foo::x = 10; // WRONG x requires object
 foo::y = 20; // ok
```

best practice:

```
 bar.x = 10; 
 foo::y = 20;
```

Comment: `bar.y = 20; // ok - but bad practice` __NO__, it's just plain __wrong__ and not allowed by the standard. Sadly VC++ provides some _extensions_ that make it legal, but it's by all means not.

Comment: @nightcracker: it's not "wrong"; `.` or `->` can be used to access any member, static or otherwise. @Artyom: why do you say it's "bad practice"?

Answer (score 0):

`.` is an instance reference (e.g. on the LHS there is an object).  `::` is a static reference.  On the RHS there is a type.

Answer (score 0):

The dot operator, also called the "class member access operator", needs an instance of a class/struct.

```
struct X
{
    static int x = 5;
    int y = 3;
}
namespace NS
{
    int z = 1;
}

void foo()
{
    X instance;
    instance.x;  // OK, class member access operator
    X::x;        // OK, qualified id-expression
    instance.y;  // OK
    X::y;        // Not OK, y is not static, needs an instance.
    NS.z;        // Not OK: NS is not an object
    NS::z;       // OK, qualified-id expression for a namespace member.
}
```

The wording is taken from C++0x FDIS.

Comment: so, who is correct here, David (saying a.b is ok for static b), or nightcracker (saying that a.b is by all means wrong if b is static)???

Comment: David: I guess it is. FDIS C++0x `9.4/2` does indeed state it is legal. Will edit.

Comment: `X.x` and `X.y` are both not OK in your example.

Comment: Interjay: see FDIS 9.4/2. It says it *is* OK.Please note this answer has been edited to be correct, and David's comment was on the previous version...

Comment: 9.4/2 says no such thing. It says you can use `Class::static_member` or `expression.static_member`.

Comment: interjay: it says explicitely: `A static member may be referred
to using the class member access syntax, in which case the object expression is evaluated.` The second part doesn't matter in my case, it does in the case of the FDIS example. `instance` in my example takes the place of your `expression` in your second code bit.

Comment: @rubenvb: but `X` isn't an object, so `X.x` and `X.y` are invalid. `instance.x` and `instance.y` would be OK.

Comment: I guess you meant to use `instance` instead of `X` then?

Comment: I have removed the comment as it no longer made sense, and fixed the code sample. As @Mike and @interjay correctly state, to use the member class access syntax you need an *instance* not a type. (And a simple run through a compiler would have told you so, I consider it *good practice* to run the code bits by a compiler to verify the results)

Comment: David: Ah yes, typos typos typos. Sorry for the confusion. My fault. Thanks for the fixup

Answer (score 0):

the `::` is for class/namespace scope, but the left hand side of `.` must be a variable in this case. Note that this would work, which might be why Intellisense works as well for you:

```
Class x;
doSomething( x.Variable );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class::StaticProperty
InstanceOfClass.Property
```