# In c++ what does -> mean?

Tags: c++, qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I use a dot, arrow, or double colon to refer to members of a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

In the code above, what does -> mean? Thanks.

Comment: That's a strangely basic question to ask from the middle of some advanced code. How did you get this far? I'd recommend reading a good book on C++ for a bit until you're familiar with all the fundamentals.

Comment: @KerrekSB, my guess is it's either an example or template project of IDE.

Comment: @Nanocom: When you put a -1 on this, Did you tell the OP what should be searched for or what book should be referred? or even pointed him/her in the right direction? Just an overzealous -1 helps no one.

Comment: This is pretty much basic and You need to pick up a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn it.

Comment: What... no one here has worked with Qt and Qt's ide (Qt Creator)? This is the basic 'template' for a Qt Gui app.

Comment: Why the hell are people downvoting this? A smug sense of superiority? It's a legitimate question, not poorly worded and polite. The only reason I can think of is that the question may be a duplicate, but there is a close vote feature for that very reason.

Comment: I downvoted it because a google search for "C++ operators" led to me wikipedia which gave a high level description of the operator. By using its suggested name I immediately found http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/ which seems to show its use nicely, showing a lack of searching as well as the fact that it's a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkB, StackOverflow aims to collect the answers for questions, not to send away beginners yelling RTFM at them. He might not even know what to search for!

Comment: @Als: everybody can do a google research...

Comment: @Nanocom: If they know what to search for!

Comment: All I can say is that How to think like a computer scientist c++ edition really isn't a good book to be reading by itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the object on the left side of the arrow is a pointer to an instance of a class or structure, and the name on the right is a member of that class or structure.

In the context:

```
ui->setupUI(this);
```

it means that `ui` is a pointer to an instance of the class `Ui::MainWindow` and the `setupUI(this)` is an invocation of the `setupUI` member function of that class with the parameter `this`.

When you have an actual instance of a class (or structure) instead of a pointer, then you use the notation:

```
Ui::MainWindow non_ptr; // not a pointer
non_ptr.setupUI(this);
```

Strictly, you can also write:

```
(*ui).setupUI(this);
```

However, you will rightly be ostracized if you write code like that rather than using the `->` arrow operator.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, `x->y` is the same as `(*x).y`. Things like iterators can overload `->` to do a bit of bonus stuff but in general it's a shorthand.

Comment: Sometimes. Unless it's not. (Operators can be overloaded in C++.)

Comment: I think that overloading these particular operators is bad form, so it should be true in most reasonable situations.

Comment: @Toomai: These operators are necessarily overloaded for e.g. iterators and smart pointers.

Comment: True, sometimes, but then you can say that about any operator that can be overloaded.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, yes they are of course overloaded for iterators, but they are overloaded in a way that it's semantically very similar (iterators mimic pointers). If not, than that's a bad practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

`ui->` is equivalent to `(*ui).` (access the member of the object pointed to by ui).

Answer (score 2):

`ui->setupUi(this)` is actually a short way of writing `(*ui).setupUi(this)`.

P.S.: Somebody had downvoted your question, so I upvoted it. To the downvoter: come on! So what if this is a trivial question? It might be a perfectly reasonable one for a person who is just starting to learn C++.

Comment: I did not downvote.But come on now.Who starts to learn `C++` with code like `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :     QMainWindow(parent),     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)`?This is very scary for a beginner....

Comment: True that. But we don't know his situation. Maybe it just so happened that he's stuck with some Qt code that he needs to fix real quick.

Comment: `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)` is exactly what will be generated by IDE on creation of a new Qt GUI application - probably the simplest starting point for a new user of Qt.

Comment: That's auto-generated code that QtCreator generates.

Answer (score 1):

It is a notation in both C and C++ to indicate that we access a variable via a pointer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ui` is a pointer type (as implied by initializing it with `new UI::MainWindow`), then `ui->setupUi` is equivalent to `*(ui).setUi`.

However, it's also possible to overload `operator->` for a class, in which case it's basically equivalent to `ui.operator->(whatever)`. It's probably worth noting that the semantics of an overloaded `operator->` are somewhat unusual: `x->` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->y`, so the overloaded `operator->` must return some type for which `returned_object->y` is also legal -- either another object that also overloads `operator->`, or else an actual pointer.