# Arrow vs dot syntax?

Tags: c++, c, syntax

A friend is taking a data structures course and I'm trying to explain the difference in the context of a linked list. I really should know this, but having focused on high level frameworks, I'm a little rusty. I know that "arrows are used with pointers", but that's it.

Essentially, in C, what's the difference between a dot and and an arrow when accessing a property of some variable? Also, because I'm in a particularly stupid mood, is this the same in C++, or did it change?

Comment: Also highly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c

Comment: Good catch, not sure why I couldn't find it.

Comment: Your friend should read a primer on the C or C++ language.

Comment: If you're *that* shaky on C syntax and concepts, you shouldn't be trying to explain things ... you'll just mislead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally the `.` is used when you have a structure to access directly, and the `->` when you have a pointer to a structure and need to dereference it to access the structure.

`a->b` is syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`.  It's the same in both C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

`myPtr->someVariable` is the same as `(*myPtr).someVariable` (dereferences myPtr, accesses the member). If you have `*myPtr.someVariable` it treats `(myPtr.someVariable)` as the pointer (access the member, dereference the whole thing as the pointer).

Answer (score 1):

```
pointersomething->member
```

is the same thing as

```
(*pointersomething).member
```

it exists as a shortcut as one could in theory do

```
*pointersomething.member
```

But the . operators have greater precedence than * operators, so the parenthesis are necessary- and thus the arrow shortcut.