# Converting from Java to C++. Why can't I use methods of a different class the same way in C++?

Tags: java, c++

I'm trying to convert a Java program to C++. This is the Java code (which IS working perfectly):

```
//class MyProgram:

public class MyProgram {
    private static ArrayList mylist;
    //no constructor
    public static int numberOfItems(){
        return mylist.size();
    }
}

//second Java program, MyList

public class MyList {
    public MyList(){
        for (int i = 0; i < MyProgram.numberOfItems; i++)
            System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

This works exactly as I'd hope. However, when converting to C++, the for loop header is giving me errors because it doesn't recognize numberOfItems. The implementation is exactly the same, except a vector instead of an arraylist. My question is: why does not NOT work in C++? Why DOES it work in Java? I've never written an object before where I didn't have to call the constructor to use the methods of that class. How can I achieve this same thing in c++? I can post the c++ code but it looks extremely similar and it seems pointless.

---

EDIT: C++ CODE:

```
//MyProgram.h

#ifndef MYPROGRAM_H_
#define MYPROGRAM_H_

 #include <vector>

namespace std;

class MyProgram {
public:

    int numberOfItems();

private:
    vector<Checkpoint> mylist;


};

#endif /* MYPROGRAM_H_ */

//MyProgram.cpp

#include "MyProgram.h"

int MyProgram::numberOfItems()
{
    return mylist.size();
}

//MyList.h:

#ifndef MYLIST_H_
#define MYLIST_H_

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MyList {
public:
    MyList();
    virtual ~MyList();
private:
    vector<Checkpoint> path;

};

#endif /* MYLIST_H_ */


//mylist.cpp

#include "MyList.h"

MyList::MyList()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MyProgram.numberOfItems(); i++)
    {
        path.push_back(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add what you did in C++? It is impossible for us to see what is wrong without.

Comment: class itself needs to be static?

Comment: You haven't posted the code.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson I am adding it in now. It will take a second with the .h files and all that

Comment: @user2130057 Please do *not* use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  They are *not* the same language.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @PaulMcKenzie. Write what you need directly in C++.

Comment: @user2130057 You also need to initialize those `static` members in one and only one module otherwise you will get linker errors when building the program.

Comment: In your Java code your members are `static` but they are not `static` in your C++ code. Beyond that, please just forget about Java when learning C++, it will just hold you back and encourage you to do things the wrong way because C++ works very differently to Java.

Answer (score 4):

change `MyProgram.numberOfItems` to `MyProgram::numberOfItems()`

Comment: And you should put ()

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I am looking for. Question though, it didn't work with (), only when I removed that did it work. That being the case, what would I do if the method I wanted to call had parameters? In this case it was void so all was well.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a misunderstanding of is a class member vs object member. This post will provide you the information that you really need:
[When do I use a dot, arrow, or double colon to refer to members of a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c).

Also, like frinji1 said, `MyProgram::numberOfItems()` is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, I think my core understanding is off. I appreciate the answer.