# Complicated syntax (classes)

Tags: c++

I stumbled upon weird (for me) construction in B. Stroustrup's book. The code is

```
int (S::*) pmf() {&S::f};
```

I am intermediate in C++, but I don't even know, what should I look for in Google and SO. I don't understand above construction, can you help me or point me to a good source?

Comment: Should be `int (S::*pmf)() {&S::f}` and it means "`pmf` is a pointer to member function of `S` that takes no arguments and returns `int`, initialized to the address of the member function `S::f`.

Comment: perhaps this will shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c

Comment: Lookup for [member function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5Dmember+function+pointer+what+is)

Comment: I gave up understanding function pointer declarations (member function declarations are worse), and google it every time, if I really need some. On the other hand, std::function with a signature is nice.

Comment: You misspelled it, but here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/0okuhS) of what you may have meant.

Comment: So it is misspelled in the book (polish version), I thought it is some kind of tricky and exotic coding ;] Thanks guys for your answers and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pmf()` is a member function pointer for a member function `S::f` which return `int` and accept no parameters.