# Enum within Struct

Tags: c++, struct, enums

I'm new to enum and struct, I'm getting difficulty on how to debug this code. As long as I know, this code is already true and it should output 0 since male is at 0 position inside the gender.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct Employee{
   int number;
   enum gender{Male,Female};
   enum language{English,Mandarin};
   enum experience{onetofiveyears,fivetotenyears};
}personality;

int main(){
    personality.gender d = Male;
    cout << d;
}
```

I have no idea on how to fix this. I hope you guys want to help me cause I already did some research and it didn't work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: Are you trying to make a `d` of type `Employee::gender` (a stand-alone gender) or are you trying to access peronality's gender?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - no, no, no. *Don't* do that.

Comment: I'm trying to access the personality's gender and print the position of Male.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the enumeration using scope resolution.

```
Employee::gender d = Employee::gender::Male;
std::cout << d;
```

Comment: What's the difference between :: and dot(.). Yes it has only warning if I use :: but it gives me error if I used dot(.).

Comment: `.` refers to members of an object. An enumeration declaration within an object is not itself a member. You can create a member instance of an enumeration, which you can then refer to with the `.`. [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c)