# What is the difference between "this" and "::"?

Tags: c++

Inside setMyInt function I have used two statements to set myInt variable. Though both of them gives me the same result. Is there any conceptual difference in working of them?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Bar{
    int myInt;

public:
    const int getMyInt() const {
        return myInt;
    }

    void setMyInt(int myInt) { 

        Bar::myInt = myInt;
       this->myInt=myInt;
    }
};

int main(){
    Bar obj;
    obj.setMyInt(5);
    cout<<obj.getMyInt();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c

Comment: The result is the same, but they mean different things `this` is a pointer to your object. While :: is for scoping and here it says that you want to use the `myint` variable that is a member of your class and not the argument.

Comment: You need an example that has inheritance to observe a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really compare them, and they are not interchangeable, but because in C++ you can leave certain things out in certain cases, here it looks like they are.

In fact, both lines are short for:

```
this->Bar::myInt = myInt;
```

This means, set the value of the object `Bar::myInt` (the member called `myInt` in the scope of the class `Bar`), which is encapsulated by the object pointed to by `this`, to the value of the (other) variable `myInt`.

You can leave out `Bar::` because `this` is a `Bar*` so that's implicit; you can leave out `this->` because you're in a member function so that's implicit too.

More generally, `->` performs a pointer dereference and object access, whereas `::` is the "scope resolution operator" which fully qualifies a *name*.

Comment: Disclaimer: I've simplified some things here, but I kind of had to, because omg C++ name lookup rules

Answer (score -1):

“->” is used as a pointer
“.” Is used for object members variables/ methods
“::” Is used for static variables/ methods or for objects from another scope.

Comment: `::` can also be used for non static members

Comment: Or from the same scope, even though it's pointless. Not sure quite why this was downvoted tbh.